# Datagrid Row style binding to dynamically changing property

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hi Guys: I am trying to style datagrid row. The flow is that based on a field in the grid (MsgType) I need to color the row. The color (both back and fore) is configurable by the user in the preferences screen and I save this configuration in an observable collection for each MsgType. The user can change this configuration through preferences screen. I need to bind the color (which can change) to the row for that MsgType. I have tried the following approach and the binding works only first time....since MsgType does not change. The color is fetched by the converter based on the msgtype.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MsgType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource MessageTypeToBackConverter}}"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding MsgType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource MessageTypeToForeConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I feel I might be taking the wrong approach.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the behavior is working perfectly fine based on the your biding...

You have two options...

Keeping your code as it is, whenever preferences change, call `DataGrid.Items.Refresh()` or rebind the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property to regenerate `DataGridRows`. This way they will take the effect of the changed preferences (i.e. bg and fg colors would refresh).

The better way is to revamp your logic to use `DynamicResources` based `Brushes` to color the `DataGridRows` via `Triggers` assuming that `MsgType` values are finite & well known at compile time ...

E.g.

Assuming that your `MsgType` is some enum so it is well defined in terms of number of values it represents....

```
public enum MsgType
{
  None = 0,
  Read = 1,
  Edit = 2,
  Delete = 3
}
```

**XAML**

```
 <DataGrid.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="MyDefaultPreferences.xaml"/>
          </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>              
       </ResourceDictionary>
 </DataGrid.Resources>
 ...
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
     <Setter property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource NoneMsgTypeBrush}" />
     <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MsgType}" Value="1">
             <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource ReadMsgTypeBrush}" />
         </DataTrigger>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MsgType}" Value="2">
             <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource EditMsgTypeBrush}" />
         </DataTrigger>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MsgType}" Value="3">
             <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource DeleteMsgTypeBrush}" />
         </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

`MyDefaultPreferences.xaml` looks like below...

```
   <ResourceDictionary 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"   
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NoneMsgTypeBrush" Color="White"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ReadMsgTypeBrush" Color="Gray"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="EditMsgTypeBrush" Color="Green"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DeleteMsgTypeBrush" Color="Red"/>       </ResourceDictionary>
```

So all you have to do at runtime, when user changes the preferences, just remove and add the `Brushes` with same keys in `MyDefaultPreferences.xaml` (its a `Dictionary`)...

E.g.

If user changes Read Msg Type to be Yellow, all you have to do it this...

```
 Uri uri = new Uri("MyDefaultPreferences.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
 var _myDefaultResourceDictionary = Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary;
 _myDefaultResourceDictionary.Remove("ReadMsgTypeBrush");
 _myDefaultResourceDictionary.Add("ReadMsgTypeBrush", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
```

This removal and addition of a Brush resource, changes the color wherever it is referred via `DynamicResource` (i.e. in the corresponding `SolidColorBrush`).

**This is a very common way of changing skins \ themes of WPF applications at runtime.**

Comment: Thank WPF-it, As a quick solution I have used Items.Refresh() solution and it works fine. I will change the code slightly to use DynamicResources so that it is done correctly. Really appreciate your quick response.